# MVC5 Display Data From Database Returning Null In View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not sure what is wrong, in my home controller I am collecting the data from the database and assigning it to a model

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Edited For Security Reasons
            UserManager.Manager manager = new UserManager.Manager();

            var data = manager.GetAllUsers();
            var userDetails = from u in data
                              select new UserDetail
                              {
                                  UserID = u.Id,
                                  Username = u.Name,
                                  UserLogin = u.Login,
                                  FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                  Surname = u.Surname,
                                  Email = u.Email,
                                  Active = Convert.ToInt32(u.Active),
                                  RightID = u.RightsId,
                                  GroupID = u.GroupsId,
                              };
            userDetails.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

This is populating the userDetails as it has the values when I click it after leaving a breakpoint at `return View();`

**Model**

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string UserLogin { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }
    public List<int> RightID { get; set; }
    public List<int> GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

Visual Studio is telling me the problem is with my `@foreach (var item in Model)` that it is returning `null` but i don't understand how it can be `null` when it is being populated in the Home Controller.

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.UserDetail>

<table class="table" id="tbData" cellspacing="5" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>UserID</th>
        <th>UserLogin</th>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Active/th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.UserID)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.UserLogin)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FirstName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Surname)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Email)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Active)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning your model:

```
userDetails.ToList();
return View();
```

Do so:

```
return View(userDetails.ToList());
```

Comment: Don't dump your errors under all answers, research them yourself and if you can't figure it out, add a new question. These answers fixed your problem.

Comment: I apologise, I am new to Stack @CodeCaster

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything to your view that's why you cant get any data from the database

so what you have to do is return the list of the users to the view and make sure your model data in your view is of **IEnumerable or List**

```
var userDetails = from u in data
                          select new UserDetail
                          {
                              UserID = u.Id,
                              Username = u.Name,
                              UserLogin = u.Login,
                              FirstName = u.FirstName,
                              Surname = u.Surname,
                              Email = u.Email,
                              Active = Convert.ToInt32(u.Active),
                              RightID = u.RightsId,
                              GroupID = u.GroupsId,
                          }.ToList();
return View(userDetails)
```